# JS: Make a Div Clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to use JS to make a DIV link to outbound URL. What is the best approach? I looked into the jQuery .wrap method, but I was having issues with the URL's // ... JS thought I was commenting/

Comment: The best approach is to use an `<a>` around or instead of the `<div>`. And no JavaScript.

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you could show us different approaches you did, maybe we could comment on (dis)advantages of them. Before that,  I think this is rather opinion-based.

Comment: Mmh, [read the jQuery tutorial about event handling](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/)?

Comment: @minitech I'm not sure if I understand the question correctly, but I think he specifically asked about using Javascript to do that

Comment: Don’t use any of the existing solutions, by the way. They’re all really bad. Except for perhaps Carl’s last option, though `href` shouldn’t be inline.

Comment: I have to use JS ... I can't hardcode the anchor in the DOM. The use case is that I have mobile detection enabled, and if the user is on mobile the site behaves differently. I had understand event handling.

So the event would be on touchstart. It's the method where I'm getting stuck. I'm not sure how to wrap a div with an anchor tag using JS

Comment: “Mobile detection” sounds like a bad idea and starting navigation on `touchstart` is just kind of wrong. What if the user wants to open the link in a new tab?

Comment: What is wrong with mobile detection? I have different functionality for mobile. What mobile event would you use to replace click?

Comment: It depends on how you’re doing “mobile detection”. As for a replacement for click: nothing? Use a link.

Comment: I can't hardcode a link in the DOM. This is for the mobile version of the site.

Comment: And in the non-mobile version of the site, what do you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
$("div.mydiv").click(function(){ document.location.href = "http://bla.com"; });
```

Assuming your div was

```
<div class='mydiv'>Hello</div>
```

Alternatively i expect the wrap method would work if you were just attempting to do something like.

```
$("div.mydiv").wrap("<a href='http://bla.com'>");
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean like:

```
<div id="mydiv" onclick="document.location = 'http://google.com'">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add an onclick event to the div

```
<div onclick="window.location.href='outbound-url.com';"></div>
```